$\gamma(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t)$ is an injective smooth immersion with non-extendible velocity vector field
Consider the figure-eight curve $\gamma : (-\pi, \pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$, defined by
$$
\gamma(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t).
$$
Show that $\gamma$ is an injective smooth immersion, but that the velocity vector field $\gamma'$ is not extendible.
My try:

Smoothness and Injectivity: The curve $\gamma(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t)$ is smooth because each component is a sine function, which is smooth on $(-\pi, \pi)$. To show injectivity, observe that if $\gamma(t_1) = \gamma(t_2)$, then $\sin 2t_1 = \sin 2t_2$ and $\sin t_1 = \sin t_2$. Since $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$, the sine function is injective within this interval, meaning $t_1 = t_2$ if $\gamma(t_1) = \gamma(t_2)$. Thus, $\gamma$ is injective on $(-\pi, \pi)$.

Immersion: For $\gamma$ to be an immersion, its derivative $\gamma'(t)$ must be non-zero for all $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

Compute $\gamma'(t)$:
$$
 \gamma'(t) = \left( \frac{d}{dt} \sin 2t, \frac{d}{dt} \sin t \right) = (2 \cos 2t, \cos t).
 $$

Check if $\gamma'(t) = 0$ for any $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$: This would require both $2 \cos 2t = 0$ and $\cos t = 0$ simultaneously.

$2 \cos 2t = 0$ implies $\cos 2t = 0$, so $2t = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$, which gives $t = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{n\pi}{2}$.
$\cos t = 0$ implies $t = \frac{\pi}{2} + m\pi$.

For $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$, the only possible values of $t$ that satisfy these conditions would be $t = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, these values do not satisfy both conditions simultaneously. Therefore, $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for any $t \in (-\pi, \pi)$, confirming that $\gamma$ is indeed an immersion.



Non-Extendibility of $\gamma'$:
I have the following definition : A smooth vector field $V$ along a curve $\gamma$ on $M$ is extendible if there exists a smooth vector field $\tilde{V}$ on a neighborhood of $\gamma(I)$ such that $V = \tilde{V} \circ \gamma$.


I am having trouble using this definition to prove that $\gamma'$ is not extendible. I know that the problem is that the curve intersects itself at the origin, since $\gamma(0) = \gamma(\pi) = (0, 0)$. At this self-intersection:

$\gamma'(0) = (2, 1)$.
$\gamma'(\pi) = (2, -1)$.

However I am not sure this alone suffices as a rigorous argument. For one thing , why should I worry about $\gamma'(\pi) $ if $\pi$ is not even in the domain?After all the map is injective by the choice of the domain. Even if this argument suffices, I don't see how the definition is being used. I think I should start by considering an extension as defined and deriving a contradiction. How would you rigorously write down such an argument?

Your argument looks correct. Any ngbh as in your definitions contains $(0,0)$, and hence a ball around $(0,0)$. As you point out, $\gamma'(0)=(2,1)=\overline{V}(0,0)$, but then using continuity of $\overline{V}$ you find a contradiction with the points along "the other branch".

@WishYouTheBest how do I find that contradiction using continuity? I want to avoid writing $\gamma(\pi)$ since that is not really defined

say $U$ is a ball around $(0,0)$. Do you agree that you can find values of $\overline{V}$ as close to $(2,-1)$ as you want within $U$? (just choosing a smaller ball). And you know $\overline{V}$ should be $(2,1)$ at $(0,0)$ ... For a very formal argument, pick a sequence in $U$ converging to $(0,0)$.

@WishYouTheBest I choose $\gamma(\pi(1-1/n))$ in U but  don't know what to do there, if I take the limit I get $\gamma(\pi)$ which I don't want. How do I relate it to $\bar V$?

perhaps I need to consider a second sequence with a limit so that $\bar V$ goes to (2,-1) and so get a contradiction, but what  could that be?

Let $W$ be the neighbourhood where $\overline{V}$ will be defined. We know $\overline{V}(0,0)=(2,1)$ because $(0,0)\in W$ and $\gamma'(0,0)=(2,1)$. We also write $U$ for a ball $(0,0)\in U\subset W$.
Consider the sequence $x_n=\gamma(\pi-1/n)$. We have $x_n\to (0,0)$ and therefore $\gamma'(x_n)\to \gamma'(\pi)=(2,-1)$. For simplicity, we assume that $x_n\in U$ (otherwise start at some $n_0$ where this holds, and rename). Since $\overline{V}$ is continuos, we should have
$$
(2,1)=\lim_n \overline{V}(x_n) =\lim_n \gamma'(\pi-1/n)=(2,-1).
$$
